# ivy:retrieve select which ivy.xml file to use

Tags: java, ant, ivy

Is there a way to select which `ivy.xml` file to use when I invoke `ivy:retrieve` ?

Looking [at the documentation](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/latest-milestone/use/retrieve.html) it appears that I can use the `settingsRef` property to select which IVY settings file to use but it's not the `ivysettings.xml` file I wish to modify, rather it's `ivy.xml`. My use case is the following:

- I have a main `ivy.xml` file that I use to fetch my compile-time and run-time dependencies
- I also have a number of build tool-chain dependencies, i.e. jars used by certain Ant tasks themselves (e.g. stuff like findbugs, cobertura, pmd, code style compliance checking etc.). That's stuff that's neither a compile time nor a run-time dependency of my code. Moreover, it's the same in all the projects I am building with this tool chain so I'd like to be able to identify these dependencies in a single, separate `ivy.xml` file that I can simply copy across my projects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So this is how I did it in the end:

```
<target name="fetch-buildsystem-deps" depends="configure-ivy-settings">
    <ivy:resolve file="ivy-buildsystem.xml"/>
    <ivy:retrieve conf="build-system"
                  pattern="${lib-ivy-buildsystem.dir}/[artifact]-[revision](-[classifier]).[ext]"
                  sync="true"
                  type="jar, bundle"/>
</target>
```

… where the file `ivy-buildsystem.xml` identifies only the dependencies of my Ivy tasks. E.g. contains stuff like:

```
<configurations>
    <conf name="build-system"  description="artifacts needed by the build-system itself"/>
</configurations>
<dependencies>
    <!--dependency org="ant-contrib" name="ant-contrib" rev="1.0b3" conf="build-system->master"/-->
    <dependency org="com.puppycrawl.tools"     name="checkstyle"   rev="5.9"   conf="build-system->default"/>
    <dependency org="com.google.code.findbugs" name="findbugs-ant" rev="3.0.0" conf="build-system->default"/>
    <dependency org="net.sourceforge.pmd"      name="pmd-java"     rev="5.5.3" conf="build-system->default"/>

</dependencies>
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, but you have to specify the file in [ivy:resolve](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/latest-milestone/use/resolve.html), parameter is called `file`. The reason for his is that retrieve is a [post resolve task](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/latest-milestone/use/postresolvetask.html).

Answer (score 2):

Short anwer is to use ivy configurations:

http://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/latest-milestone/tutorial/conf.html

Ivy configurations can be used to group dependencies for different purposes. You don't need multiple ivy files.

## Example

Here's my resolve target:

```
<target name="resolve" description="Download dependencies and setup classpaths">
    <ivy:resolve/>
    <ivy:report todir='${reports.dir}/ivy' graph='false' xml='false'/>

    <ivy:cachepath pathid="compile.path" conf="compile"/>
    <ivy:cachepath pathid="test.path"    conf="test"/>
    <ivy:cachepath pathid="build.path"   conf="build"/>
</target>
```

Which can then be used directly in my various tasks that require a classpath

```
<!-- Compiling code -->
<javac srcdir="${src.dir}"... classpathref="compile.path"/>

<!-- Testing code --> 
<junit haltonfailure="yes" fork="true">
  <classpath>
    <path refid="test.path"/>
    <pathelement path="${classes.dir}"/>
    <pathelement path="${test.classes.dir}"/>
  </classpath>
  ..
</junit>

<!-- 3rd party ANT tasks -->
<taskdef uri="antlib:org.jacoco.ant" resource="org/jacoco/ant/antlib.xml" classpathref="build.path"/>

<taskdef uri="antlib:org.sonar.ant" resource="org/sonar/ant/antlib.xml" classpathref="build.path"/>

..
```

Personally I only use the retrieve task to build archives. Here again I use configurations in order to control which jars I want:

```
<ivy:retrieve pattern="${build.dir}/libs/[artifact].[ext]" conf="runtime"/>

<war destfile="${war.file}" webxml="${resources.dir}/web.xml">
  <fileset dir="${resources.dir}" excludes="web.xml"/>
  <classes dir="${build.dir}/classes"/>
  <lib dir="${build.dir}/libs"/>
</war>
```

## IVY file

```
<ivy-module version="2.0">
    <info organisation="com.myspotontheweb" module="demo"/>

    <configurations>
        <conf name="compile" description="Required to compile application"/>
        <conf name="runtime" description="Additional run-time dependencies" extends="compile"/>
        <conf name="test"    description="Required for test only" extends="runtime"/>
        <conf name="build"   description="ANT task dependencies"/>
    </configurations>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- compile dependencies -->
        <dependency org="org.slf4j" name="slf4j-api" rev="1.7.5" conf="compile->default"/>

        <!-- runtime dependencies -->
        <dependency org="org.slf4j" name="slf4j-log4j12" rev="1.7.5" conf="runtime->default"/>

        <!-- test dependencies -->
        <dependency org="junit" name="junit" rev="4.11" conf="test->default"/>

        <!-- Build dependencies --> 
        <dependency org="org.codehaus.sonar-plugins" name="sonar-ant-task" rev="2.1" conf="build->default"/>
       <dependency org="org.jacoco" name="org.jacoco.ant" rev="0.6.3.201306030806" conf="build->default"/>

    </dependencies>

</ivy-module>
```

The desired configurations are declared at the top. Note how some are set operations. For example The "compile" dependencies are automatically part of "runtime" and "test".

Secondly the configuration mappings are critical:

- **myconf->default** : Includes transitive dependencies
- **myconf->master** : Just the module jar without dependencies

Comment: Upvoted. However, I was aware of the possibility of employing different configurations. I was specifically asking for separate IVY files as I like to have the same "ANT task dependencies" across multiple projects and having separate IVY files makes that easy to check (using diff or even symlinks) whereas with your solution you have to visually inspect the files to satisify yourself that the "ANT task dependencies" are indeed the same (asuming it matters to you of course). I believe I have achieved that but until I post my own answer I am happy to accept your answer as it is a great writeup.

Comment: Incidentally, I dont like using `ivy:cachepath`  as it is a bit opaque as to the jars that actually get included. I use `ivy:retrieve` even for the "ANT task dependencies" as I like to be able to examine a directory on the filesystem and see all the jars that were brought in. `ivy:cachepath` provides no such visibillity as far as I am aware.

Comment: @MarcusJuniusBrutus Note how my "resolve" target uses the ivy "report" task to generate a detailed report of the jars on each configuration.